# Slow audio directions when using TTS in iOS9

Tags: ios, ios9, skmaps

Since we upgraded to iOS9, the audio directions (we use TTS) have a distorted/slow voice. Is there a way we can handle TTS' utterance so it speaks at a normal pace? Any other solution you are aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS 9 (using Xcode 6.4) you need to use lower values for the rate in the SKAdvisorSettings. See the documentation: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec24